# DAX measure to count rows of one table with unique IDs, where a joined table with multiple rows per ID have inconsistent values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of Work Orders and a table of related Time, with entries for Travel and Labour, that have individual flags for whether the time is Billable, and I am trying to create a measure to tell me the Work Orders that have different of Billable flags on the Travel and Labour lines.

**Work Order** table

| Work Order | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-12 |
| 2 | 2023-10-12 |
| 3 | 2023-10-12 |

**Time** table

| Work Order | Type | Hours | Billable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRAVEL | 1 | Y |
| 1 | LABOUR | 1 | Y |
| 2 | TRAVEL | 1 | N |
| 2 | LABOUR | 1 | N |
| 3 | TRAVEL | 1 | Y |
| 3 | LABOUR | 1 | N |

I need a measure in this example to have a value of 1; WO 1 and 2 are ok because both lines have the same Billable value, but WO 3 should get counted because it has both a Y and a N.

Count Work Order where ( Count Time.Billable = Y ) >= 1 && ( Count Time.Billable = N ) >= 1

I can count the Work Orders with billable lines and without billable lines, but can't figure out how to count only the Work Orders where there are both values present. I have tried with some CALCULATE formulas and COUNTROWS, DISTINCTCOUNT, I think I might need to use COUNTX...? I could do this easily in SQL but the only option here is to do it in Power BI using a measure.

Note that in the real data the tables are much more complex and there are actually 8 different categories of time to be considered, not just TRAVEL and LABOUR.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following formula Power BI will count all the workorders that have more than 1 distinct value in the Billable column. As long as all the Billable values are the same (either Y or N) it won't be counted.

```
CALCULATE( COUNT(WorksOrders[Work Order]), FILTER( WorksOrders,CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Times[Billable]) > 1) ) )
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this that evaluates once per row of `Work Order`, and checks whether there are two "valid" rows in `Time`. If a `Work Order` only has 1 billable row, it will add 1 to the iterative sum:

```
Work Order Count =
SUMX ( 
    'Work Order',
    VAR _rows = 
        CALCULATE ( 
            COUNTROWS ( 'Time' ) , 
            'Time'[Billable] = "Y" 
        )
    RETURN
    IF ( _rows = 1 , 1 )
)
```

Edit: Your requirements in the original post are tacked on during the post itself. If you have 8 rows in `Time` per `Work Order`, you can check each `Work Order` for more than 0 and less than 8 counts of `Billable = 'Y'`, since this would constitute a `Work Order` with more than one value of `Billable`:

```
Work Order Count =
SUMX ( 
    'Work Order',
    VAR _rows = 
        CALCULATE ( 
            COUNTROWS ( 'Time' ) , 
            'Time'[Billable] = "Y" 
        )
    RETURN
    IF ( _rows > 0 && _rows < 8 , 1 )
)
```

A third option is to simply count rows over a filtered table :

```
Work Order Count = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER ( 
        VALUES ( 'Work Order'[Work Order] ) , 
        CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Time'[Billable] ) ) > 1
    )
)
```

I don't have the ability to verify these measures in an actual Power BI environment right now, but hopefully this is of help.